# Eclipse crashing, getting heap exceptions - Out of Memory when trying to deploy an Android applicaiton

Tags: java, android, exception, crash, heap-memory

I have one Android project that crashes when it is deployed.  Other projects in the same workspace work fine.  I increased the RAM usage on the AVD that I'm using to 1 GB.  I don't think there is a memory leak because it seems to work on other peoples computer.

I'd like to use the Memory Profiler, but the project crashes before launching, and I can't reach the Logcat files.

Right now I'm using eclipse, is there a way for me to launch it using ANT or the command line, where I can execute it step by step and find where the crash is happening?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

david

Try to increase heap size of the eclipse in vm arguments from eclipse.ini file for example by default it will like

```
  -vmargs
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -Xms40m
  -Xmx512m
```

You can change something like

```
  -vmargs 
  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
  -Xms512m
  -Xmx1024m
  -XX:PermSize=256M
  -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```