# Why does xalan.jar crash eclipse when deploying android app

Tags: android, eclipse, out-of-memory, xalan

I am developing an android app on Eclipse Juno running on Windows 7 64bit (8GB ram) So I have my android project and I place some jar files in the /lib folder so I can use them in my app. This is fine, up until I add the xalan.jar file which is needed as a dependency for an apache xml parser.

When I try to run/deploy my app from eclipse so it can run on my phone, I start seeing compiler warnings in the console complaining about classes from xalan.jar and then Eclipse crashes with a out-of-memory heap space exception.

```
!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2013-01-20 21:04:37.427
!MESSAGE Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
!STACK 0
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.getRopLabelSuccessorList(SsaBasicBlock.java:393)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertBasicBlock(SsaToRop.java:299)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertBasicBlocks(SsaToRop.java:260)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convert(SsaToRop.java:124)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertToRopMethod(SsaToRop.java:70)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:102)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor23.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:745)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
```

I tried searching online but closest thing I found was a stackoverflow question [Eclipse crashing, getting heap exceptions - Out of Memory when trying to deploy an Android applicaiton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212951/eclipse-crashing-getting-heap-exceptions-out-of-memory-when-trying-to-deploy) which instructs to increase the heap-space memory. Which I did from 256m to 1024 and I still get the error.

I remove xalan.jar and everything deploys normally. Are there any solutions to this?

**------------EDIT-------------**

After updating max memory to 2048

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.android.dx.util.IntList.<init>(IntList.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RopMethod.calcPredecessors(RopMethod.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.rop.code.RopMethod.labelToPredecessors(RopMethod.java:95)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:158)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:174)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:104)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:45)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:99)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:73)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:273)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:134)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:87)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:487)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:398)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:422)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:333)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:209)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:745)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
```

Comment: From everything I'm reading, xalan.jar is an implementation of a package in javax which is not included in the SDK. That is most likely the cause of the compiler warnings in the console. Correction http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/package-summary.html It's not included till Android API 8. So if your minimum build target is 8 or greater and your SDK up to date, this is moot.

Comment: my minimum target is API 14. So what you're telling me is that xalan.jar and xml-apis.jar are not needed for API 8 and up? More importantly my server back end is running on JDK 1.6u38 so I probably don't needed those 2 specific jars. btw I am using them because I am using XOM (www.xom.nu) which depends on them. But my droid app is working ok without xalan and xml-apis.

Comment: Well... if it works without it, it works without it. My impression is that this wouldn't work at all without the javax dependency in android, and if something needed xalan it would be using that as an interface to that javax package. But again, if the XOM functions without it, get rid of xalan.

Comment: I'll read up a bit more on XOM and do some extra tests concerning xom, mayb try running their unit cases and see how it goes without xalan. Could you also post this as an answer, for getting the bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you something definitive.  From www.xom.nu:

> **Java 1.3 and earlier do not have a built-in XML parser so in these environments you'll also need to install XOM's supporting libraries. These include xalan.jar,** xercesImpl.jar, normalizer.jar, and xml-apis.jar, and are found in the lib directory. The versions shipped with XOM are quite a bit faster and less buggy than the ones bundled with the JDK, so you may well want to use them even in Java 1.4 and later. For example,
>
> $ java -classpath xom-samples.jar:xom-1.1.jar:lib/xml-apis.jar:lib/xercesImpl.jar:lib/normalizer.jar:lib/xalan.jar nu.xom.samples.PrettyPrinter filename.xml
>
> You can leave out xalan.jar if you don't use any of the classes in nu.xom.xslt. normalizer.jar is needed in all versions of Java. However, it's only actually used by the setUnicodeNormalizationFormC() method in Serializer. If you don't call this method, you can omit this archive in space-limited environments. junit.jar is only used for testing, and is not needed for normal operation of XOM.

So leave off xalan.jar. Android's native javax.xml.transform does all that work already (as of API 8).

Incidentally, looks like you may be able to drop some other jars as well.

Comment: Great! I dove into the docs after reading your post and I can safely say that this case is solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be cause by the default Eclipse configuration for the JVM. 
Make sure you add some more space to your JVM heap.

```
-Xms512M -Xmx2048M
```

Here are some references on how to accomplish this

http://edwards.sdsu.edu/research/index.php/daniel/236-increasing-heap-size-in-eclipse

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Also, double check that you have your ADT plugin and Android SDK tools updated.

Comment: I had previously increased it to 1024, I increased it to 2048 and double checked it using a small program as depicted in your link. I added xalan.jar in the libs folder and ran it. Eclipse crashed so badly it shut itself down. The exception is posted above.